# Error on cloning fossil: "Attempt to write a readonly database"

Tags: repository, clone, fossil

This is the first time I've attempt to host a fossil repository on my personal server.  When I try to clone a project on Windows 7, I get a bizarre message:

```
PS [folder]> fossil clone 'http://[hostName]/cgi-bin/repo/[repoName]' [repoName].fossil
                Bytes      Cards  Artifacts     Deltas
Sent:              53          1          0          0
Received:         218          1          0          0
Sent:              58          1          0          0
Error: Database error: attempt to write a readonly database
UPDATE event SET mtime=(SELECT m1 FROM time_fudge WHERE mid=objid) WHERE objid IN (SELECT mid FROM time_fudge);DROP TABLE time_fudge;
Received:         218          1          0          0
Total network traffic: 515 bytes sent, 858 bytes received
C:\Program Files (x86)\Fossil\fossil.exe: server returned an error - clone aborted
```

What does the error message mean?  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Can you browse `http://[hostName]/cgi-bin/repo/[repoName]` correctly? It seems that the error is on the server side. Is the fossil repository file writable by the http server?

Comment: Excellent question.  I just tried it now.  I can navigate to it, but I cannot login.  It seems unwritable even by the http server.

Comment: Is it, by chance, related to (linux) permissions?  I've made all the fossil repositories owned by root, with read permissions for everyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I think I figured out the writing problem.  I've changed the group permissions of each fossil file to `www-data`, and allowed the group to read and write.

```
$ sudo chown :www-data *.fossil
$ sudo chmod g+w *.fossil
```

That seemed to have solved that problem.